# Adding users to VPN Server on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows-10, vpn, powershell, user-accounts, group-policy

I have set up a VPN server on a completely fresh Windows 10 Pro (1607) install, I've followed the steps in this guide.

http://www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software/

The VPN server works correctly, and the users I specified during setup have access.

However, as I am not going to be managing the server, I want to make it as simple as possible for my end-user to add new accounts.

I hoped that it would be possible to give users access based on their Group. Then I could make a VPN group, which users could easily be added to, however this doesn't seem to be possible?

Failing that, I would like a script, that could be run, specifying user info, which, if chosen, will add the user to the VPN access list. However, I can not seem to find a command for batch or powershell that does this.

Is there any other ideas I could use to easily add (and if possible, remove) users from the VPN list?

Answer (score 1):

As there is almost no information on the subject in the internet I may only suggest either doing a registry trace or pre-provisioning of VPN accounts.

That is you create in advance inactive users `vpn01`, `vpn02`, ... `vpn99'. Give those users access to VPN. Then you can turn them on/off:

```
net user vpn02 /active:yes
net user vpn02 /active:no
```

Windows stores all settings in registry. Apparently VPN settings are stored there as well. Run `Incoming connections` wizard and track registry activity with say [process monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx). With some effort it will be possible understand registry keys involved and write related powershell script.